# An otherwise linear matrix equation with the presence of a signum function : reference request

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, matrix-equations

Consider the equation $$\pmb{c}+\text{sign}(G\pmb{c}) = L$$

$\pmb{c}$ is a $n\times1$ matrix.

$G$ is a $n\times n$ matrix which is also positive definite.

matrices $G$ and $c$ are real.

$L$ is a $n\times 1$ matrix whose entries are from the set $\{-1,1\}$.

Can this equation be solved for the matrix $\pmb{c}$?
Suppose there is no signum function there, then the solution is $$\pmb{c} = (G+I_n)^{-1}L$$
and as $G$ is positive definite, there exists a unique solution. But with the presence of the $\text{sign}$ function, the problem doesn't seem to belong to linear algebra. I request for a reference to any subject or book for this type of equations. Does this belong to linear programming?(I don't know anything about it, so I am hoping it is related).

PS: please tag appropriately.

PS 2: $\text{sign}([a_{i,j}]_{m\times n}) = [\text{sign}(a_{i,j})]_{m\times n}$.

Comment: Cross-posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3842071/an-otherwise-linear-matrix-equation-with-the-presence-of-a-signum-function-ref)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve the problem via mixed integer linear programming as follows.  Let $\epsilon>0$ be a small constant tolerance. For $i \in \{1,\dots,n\}$, let $[\ell_i,u_i]$ be constant lower and upper bounds on $(Gc)_i$, and let binary decision variables $z^-_i$ and $z^+_i$ indicate whether $(Gc)_i<0$ or $(Gc)_i>0$, respectively, so $\text{sign}(G\pmb{c})=\pmb{z^+}-\pmb{z^-}$.  The constraints are:
\begin{align}
c_i - z^-_i + z^+_i &= L_i &&\text{for all $i$} \tag1\\
z^-_i + z^+_i &\le 1 &&\text{for all $i$} \tag2\\
\ell_i z^-_i + \epsilon z^+_i \le (Gc)_i &\le -\epsilon z^-_i + u_i z^+_i &&\text{for all $i$} \tag3
\end{align}
Constraints $(2)$ and $(3)$ together enforce three cases:
\begin{align} 
(z^-_i,z^+_i)=(1,0) &\implies (Gc)_i\le -\epsilon < 0 \\
(z^-_i,z^+_i)=(0,0) &\implies (Gc)_i = 0 \\
(z^-_i,z^+_i)=(0,1) &\implies (Gc)_i\ge \epsilon > 0
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks RobPratt. Any algorithm available to solve this?

Comment: Branch-and-cut is the state-of-the-art algorithm for mixed integer linear programming (MILP).

Comment: One last question, I understood the constraints, but what is it that should be minimized? As I read any MILP problem has constraints and a minimization problem.

Comment: Should we minimize the tolerance $\epsilon$?

Comment: If you only care about finding a vector that satisfies the constraints, just use the constant 0 as the objective function.  More generally, you can use any linear function of the decision variables.

Comment: No, $\epsilon$ is a constant, not a decision variable.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, most of the MILP softwares ask only one inequality (one matroix inequality, one matrix equality and one bound inequality. How can I feed this problem into these software, as I here have multiple inequlities and they are not in format of the one required for these software. Any furthur processing needs to be done. It would be great if you could share some info on this. Thanks.

Comment: You will need to rewrite in matrix-vector form to use such software.  For example, constraint $(1)$ is $\pmb{c}-\pmb{z^-}+\pmb{z^+}=\pmb{L}$.  And if the software accepts only one inequality, you will need to stack $(2)$ and $(3)$.  Alternatively, you can use an algebraic modeling language to convert from the algebraic form in my answer to the input format the solver expects.